# How to append text to duplicate entries in a database using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I find duplicates and append a random number to the duplicates so that they stop being duplicates anymore.

Sample table:

```
primary_id, student_id, student_name
1           80          John Terry
2           81          Didier Drogba
3           80          John Terry
4           82          Frank Lampard
5           80          John Terry
```

I want to get rid of duplicates by appending a random number to the name of the duplicate. E.g. in the above scenario, I want to rename 
the student_name that appears on rows 3 to `112233_DUP_John Terry` and on row 5 to `668877_DUP_John Terry`. Note that the first entry of the duplicate remains unchanged. In this case row 1 remains unchanged.

The format for renaming is: `6_digit_random_number` + `_DUP_` + `Existing Student Name`

So far I can be able to get the duplicates using the SQL below:

```
SELECT student_id, student_name FROM (select student_id, student_name, count(*) from student
          group by student_id, student_name
          HAVING count(*) > 1 order by count DESC) AS duplicates
```

I know I can also generate a random number using SQL but I cant figure out how to append it to the duplicate entries

Am running Postgresql database

Comment: Please show your expected results. If the dup rows have the same student ID and name, why don't you just delete the duplicates?

Comment: Your data as SQLFiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5b1b8 . Please try to supply this in future, it saves time and frustration.

Comment: @CraigRinger the business case is that am required to keep all the data. Can't delete -not now anyway. I do have a column for `is_deleted` which is boolean which I have already marked as `True` but the data has to remain. ooh, thanks for the sqlfiddle link. Didn't know about such a service

Answer (score 4):

First get rows that are duplicates using a window function instead of your group method, e.g.

```
SELECT
  primary_id, student_id, student_name
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id, student_name) AS dup_no,
    primary_id, student_id, student_name
  FROM students
) dup
WHERE dup.dup_no > 1;
```

then combine that with an `UPDATE ... FROM` to update just the duplicates:

```
UPDATE students
SET student_name = to_char(dupstudents.dup_no, '000000') || '_DUP_' || students.student_name
FROM (
  SELECT
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id, student_name) AS dup_no,
    primary_id, student_id, student_name
  FROM students
) dupstudents
WHERE students.primary_id = dupstudents.primary_id
  AND dupstudents.dup_no > 1;
```

e.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5b1b8/9

I haven't bothered with the "random ID" bit; I just used the duplicate offset position. Feel free to replace it with a suitable call to `(random()*10^6)::integer` or whatever, but beware of random value collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select student_id, R_N, student_name, 
  CASE WHEN R_N <> 1 THEN to_char( r_n,'000000')||'_DUP_' ELSE '' END ||student_name  
  FROM (SELECT *,
    row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY student_name) as R_N  from student) AS T1
```

tested by [sql fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0bc33/16)

Use random number:

```
select student_id, R_N, student_name, 
  CASE WHEN R_N <> 1 THEN to_char(random()*1000000,'000000')||'_DUP_' ELSE '' END ||student_name  
  FROM (SELECT *,
    row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY student_name) as R_N  from student) AS T1
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0bc33/22)

In one statement without subquery:

```
select student_id,
       row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY student_name) ,
       student_name, 
       CASE WHEN row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY student_name) <> 1 
       THEN to_char( random()*1000000,'000000')||'_DUP_' ELSE '' END ||student_name  
from student
;
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0bc33/25)

Answer (score 0):

following up on [Craig Ringer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25111183/3682599)

```
with cte as 
(
  SELECT
  primary_id, student_id, student_name
  FROM 
   (
    SELECT
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY stu_id, stu_name) AS dup_no,
    primary_id, student_id, student_name
    FROM student
   ) dup
  WHERE dup.dup_no > 1 
),cte2 as(
select (to_char(random()*1000000,'000000')) || '_DUP_' ||student_name as 
duplictaestudentname,primary_id,student_id from student where primary_id in (select    
primary_id from cte)
)
update student as v 
set student_name=s.duplictaestudentname
from cte2 as s
where v.primary_id=s.primary_id
```

Comment: Your code works but I can't figure out where to insert the update statement that will actually do the update to the student_name like what @craig Ringer did